# JavaFX GridPane is resizing instead of holding position with new amount of Constraints

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

My task is to create an UI with a navigation tab on the left and a gridpane on the right (Scroll down for ui). 
First of all, I initialized the grid by adding Row- and Columnconstraints to it. It works completely fine after first starting the program.

It looks like:

[image]

After pressing the apply button with updated values, it seems  that the initialized matrix is still there, with putting the new Constraints on top of the older values.

[image]

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            HBox root = new HBox();
            VBox settings = new VBox();
            GridPane matrix = new GridPane();
            Button applyButton = new Button("Apply settings");
            TextField sizeMatrix = new TextField("size");
            TextField amountLivingCells = new TextField("living Cells");

            matrix.setMinHeight(400);
            matrix.setMinWidth(400);
            matrix.setMaxHeight(400);
            matrix.setMaxWidth(400);

            final int initialSize = 12;
            final int initialAmountBlackCells = 30;

            NumberBinding size = Bindings.min(matrix.widthProperty(),
                    matrix.heightProperty().subtract(50))
               .divide(20);

            //binding for size rounded down
            NumberBinding roundedSize = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> size.intValue(), size);

            //initialize matrix
            setConstraints(matrix, initialSize);

            //fill out matrix with white Rectangles
            setBlankRectangles(matrix, roundedSize, initialSize);


            setRandomlyBlackRectangles(matrix, initialAmountBlackCells, initialSize);

            applyButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeMatrix.getText());
                    int amountCells = Integer.parseInt(amountLivingCells.getText());

                    LogicMinimal.newMatrix(matrix, size);
                    LogicMinimal.fillMatrixWithDeadCells(matrix, size);
                    LogicMinimal.randomlySetLivingCells(matrix, amountCells, size);
                }
            });


            root.getChildren().addAll(settings, matrix);
            settings.getChildren().addAll(sizeMatrix, amountLivingCells, applyButton);
            settings.setSpacing(20);


            Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setRandomlyBlackRectangles(GridPane matrix, int amount, int sizeMatrix) {
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                int randomCol = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, sizeMatrix + 1);
                int randomRow = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, sizeMatrix + 1);

                for (Node node : matrix.getChildren()) 
                {
                    if (node instanceof Rectangle && 
                        GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == randomCol && 
                        GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == randomRow) 
                    {
                        Rectangle cell = (Rectangle)node;
                        cell.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    private void setBlankRectangles(GridPane matrix, NumberBinding roundedSize, int size) {
        for(int column = 0; column < size; column++)
        {
           for(int row = 0; row < size; row++)
              {
               Rectangle dead_cell = new Rectangle();
               dead_cell.setFill(Color.WHITE);
               dead_cell.widthProperty().bind(roundedSize);
               dead_cell.heightProperty().bind(roundedSize);

               GridPane.setColumnIndex(dead_cell, column);
               GridPane.setRowIndex(dead_cell, row);
               matrix.add(dead_cell, column, row);             
              }
         }
    }

    private void setConstraints(GridPane matrix, int size) {

        matrix.getRowConstraints().removeAll(matrix.getRowConstraints());
        matrix.getColumnConstraints().removeAll(matrix.getColumnConstraints());

        double cellWidth;
        double cellHeight;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
          ColumnConstraints colConst = new ColumnConstraints();
          cellWidth = 100.0 / size;
          colConst.setPercentWidth(cellWidth);    
          matrix.getColumnConstraints().add(colConst);

          RowConstraints rowConst = new RowConstraints();
          cellHeight = 100.0 / size;
          rowConst.setPercentHeight(cellHeight);
          matrix.getRowConstraints().add(rowConst);  
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your question.  A [mcve] may help (make sure it is minimal, complete and replicates the issue).  Perhaps look at this [example of a resizable grid](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2030464), maybe some of the techniques there might help you, maybe not.

Comment: Some vertical lines in your grid image are missing, why does it look like that?  Is that an issue you are asking about?  Or is that just some other bug not related to the question?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my request...hopefully its way more understandably. @jewelsea I think the missing lines are just bugs regarding the "setGridLinesVisible(true)" for debugging

Comment: It isn't a [mcve], it is just a lot easier, a lot of time to work with a [mcve] (something which can just be copy and pasted to replicate the issue without change and without extraneous gunk), otherwise it is so much work to try to replicate the problem.

Comment: I hope it's fine

Comment: Yes, much better, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the main problem I saw were these lines

```
LogicMinimal.newMatrix(matrix, size1);
LogicMinimal.fillMatrixWithDeadCells(matrix, size1);
LogicMinimal.randomlySetLivingCells(matrix, amountCells, size1);
```

This is because you create a new matrix and never remove the old so this caused it to still be displayed on the screen. Also you never posted the code for the `LogicMinimal` Class so I have added the necessary code to make it run properly

I have also changed the below 2 lines so that the black squares would appear in column and row 0 as well feel free to revert this change

```
int randomCol = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, sizeMatrix + 1);//Change 1 to 0 to allow to be placed in col 0
int randomRow = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, sizeMatrix + 1);//Change 1 to 0 to allow to be placed in row 0
```

This is the fully runnable class

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            HBox root = new HBox();

            TextField sizeMatrix = new TextField();
            sizeMatrix.setPromptText("Size");

            TextField amountLivingCells = new TextField();
            amountLivingCells.setPromptText("living Cells");

            Button applyButton = new Button("Apply settings");
            applyButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                //Remove Old matrix
                GridPane oldMatrix = null;
                for (Node child : root.getChildren()) {
                    if(child instanceof GridPane) {
                        oldMatrix = (GridPane) child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                root.getChildren().remove(oldMatrix);

                int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeMatrix.getText());
                int amountCells = Integer.parseInt(amountLivingCells.getText());

                //Build and Add new Matrix
                GridPane newMatrix = buildNewMatrix(size, amountCells);
                root.getChildren().add(newMatrix);

                //No longer needed
                //LogicMinimal.newMatrix(matrix, size1);
                //LogicMinimal.fillMatrixWithDeadCells(matrix, size1);
                //LogicMinimal.randomlySetLivingCells(matrix, amountCells, size1);
            });

            VBox settings = new VBox();
            settings.getChildren().addAll(sizeMatrix, amountLivingCells, applyButton);
            settings.setSpacing(20);

            GridPane matrix = buildNewMatrix(12, 30);

            root.getChildren().addAll(settings, matrix);


            Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
            //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            applyButton.requestFocus();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private GridPane buildNewMatrix(int initialSize, int initialAmountBlackCells){
        GridPane newMatrix = new GridPane();
        newMatrix.setMinHeight(400);
        newMatrix.setMinWidth(400);
        newMatrix.setMaxHeight(400);
        newMatrix.setMaxWidth(400);

        NumberBinding size = Bindings.min(newMatrix.widthProperty(),
                newMatrix.heightProperty().subtract(50))
                .divide(20);

        //binding for size rounded down
        NumberBinding roundedSize = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(size::intValue, size);

        //initialize newMatrix
        setConstraints(newMatrix, initialSize);

        //fill out newMatrix with white Rectangles
        setBlankRectangles(newMatrix, roundedSize, initialSize);

        setRandomlyBlackRectangles(newMatrix, initialAmountBlackCells, initialSize);

        return newMatrix;
    }

    private void setRandomlyBlackRectangles(GridPane matrix, int amount, int sizeMatrix) {
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            int randomCol = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, sizeMatrix + 1);//Change 1 to 0 to allow to be placed in col 0
            int randomRow = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, sizeMatrix + 1);//Change 1 to 0 to allow to be placed in row 0

            for (Node node : matrix.getChildren())
            {
                if (node instanceof Rectangle &&
                        GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == randomCol &&
                        GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == randomRow)
                {
                    Rectangle cell = (Rectangle)node;
                    cell.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setBlankRectangles(GridPane matrix, NumberBinding roundedSize, int size) {
        for(int column = 0; column < size; column++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < size; row++)
            {
                Rectangle dead_cell = new Rectangle();
                dead_cell.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                dead_cell.widthProperty().bind(roundedSize);
                dead_cell.heightProperty().bind(roundedSize);

                GridPane.setColumnIndex(dead_cell, column);
                GridPane.setRowIndex(dead_cell, row);
                matrix.add(dead_cell, column, row);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setConstraints(GridPane matrix, int size) {

        matrix.getRowConstraints().removeAll(matrix.getRowConstraints());
        matrix.getColumnConstraints().removeAll(matrix.getColumnConstraints());

        double cellWidth;
        double cellHeight;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ColumnConstraints colConst = new ColumnConstraints();
            cellWidth = 100.0 / size;
            colConst.setPercentWidth(cellWidth);
            matrix.getColumnConstraints().add(colConst);

            RowConstraints rowConst = new RowConstraints();
            cellHeight = 100.0 / size;
            rowConst.setPercentHeight(cellHeight);
            matrix.getRowConstraints().add(rowConst);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I noticed that i never removed the old matrix, but i didnt find a suitable way to change it. Btw: The Code of the Class LogicMinimal are the three Methods i posted before. I just forgot to change the names within the project

Comment: No worries if this answered your question please upvote and Accept the answer so that other don't think the topic is still open

Comment: Hi, maybe you've got another advice for me. I implemented the code as you posted before and i customized it since my pane is a BorderPane. After removing the oldMatrix, new one does not appear though. If I try to add a simple Button instead of a GridPane, everything is fine. I know its hard to diagnose, but maybe there is a thoughtless lightning :) I have to mention, that your code runs with GridPane, but without FXML and a controller.